# alternative to sympy's simplify function

Tags: python

I've been using the simplify function in Sympy to simplify some long complicated equations, but it's not proving sufficient, as it frequently does not simplify things as much as possible, giving my program numerical errors when it comes to solving the equations.

Does anyone know of any other symbolic engines with a simplify function that can be used instead?

Many thanks.

Comment: Did you try to use Sage (http://www.sagemath.org) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you use python's subprocess module to run maxima on behalf of your python program?  This is what maxima-mode on Emacs does, just do something similar. Start maxima, keep file handles to it's input/output, feed it with equations and let it mangle them to your desire (Maxima has lots of equation-changing functions), and read back the result from the output file handle.

- [Sympy vs. Maxima](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/wiki/SymPy-vs.-Maxima)
- [pyMaxima](http://www.wspiegel.de/pymaxima/index_en.html)

Comment: And this Maxima program simplifies equations better?

Comment: I'd say so...  it's very capable. However, you need to understand math a bit, in Maxima there are several functions to "simplify" a function. What is "simple" is often in the eye of the observer, but you can [look](http://hippasus.com/resources/symmath/maximasym.html) at expand(), factor(), trigsimple(), fullratsimp() and so on. Also google "Maxima by Example".

Comment: Okay I'll give it a go, but leave the question open for a bit. Given that it's numerical instability I'm having problems with it looks like fullratsimp might do what I want. Thanks very much.